# TYPO3 8.7.10: "Unknown column 'sys_file_reference.uid_local:type' in 'where clause'" in a new extension with file type property

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions, extension-builder3

everybody!

In a new TYPO3 8.7.10 site, i just created a new extension by using Extension Builder. In that extension, there is a model object ("FurnitureFamily") with a file type property (I called it "symbol"). My extension also has a plugin which displays a list of all furniture families. I created a furniture family and a new page with my plugin.

***A new model object in Extension Builder***

[image: A new model object in Extension Builder]

```
/**
 * name
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $name = '';

/**
 * symbol
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
 * @cascade remove
 */
protected $symbol = null;
```

The problem is that, instead of showing a list with my only record, I get the following error:

> Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20180219055419589a6076

With the help of the *fh_debug* extension, I can get more information about the error:

> Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20180219055419589a6076 Unknown column 'sys_file_reference.uid_local:type' in 'where clause' exception code:1472074485 file:/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Storage/Typo3DbBackend.php line:393 fh_debug trace: file: /typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Backend.php" line:226 function:getObjectDataByQuery file: /typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/PersistenceManager.php" line:126 function:getObjectDataByQuery file: /typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/QueryResult.php" line:113 function:getObjectDataByQuery file: /typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Mapper/DataMapper.php" line:567 function:getFirst file: /typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Mapper/DataMapper.php" line:503 function:mapResultToPropertyValue file: /typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Mapper/DataMapper.php" line:290 function:mapObjectToClassProperty file: /typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Mapper/DataMapper.php" line:186 function:thawProperties file: /typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Mapper/DataMapper.php" line:144 function:mapSingleRow

Curiously, when I remove the property "symbol", The list is shown (only with the property "name").

Being a new installation, I tried compare my database with the specificacion, but there were no changes to make.

My question is: How can I correct that error?

Thank you.

Comment: Normally it should write the name with a capital letter in the comment section like * Name, *Symbol.... and you don´t need @cascade remove in my opinion. Could you try to change these two things and tell what´s the output?

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old but I still had this issue in TYPO3 version 9 and discovered it it's related to extension-builder which is creating some entries for the field `uid_local:type`.
The error-message is just blocking everything because for the field is no type defined.

In this screenshot you can see that a field with that name is defined in the table `sys_file_reference`:
[image]

Scrolling a long list with table-fields down something like this can be discovered:
[image]

There a definition for `config.items` can be found which has typical definitions for some items that can be selected. Even there is only one item, the structure is typical for some kind of form-element for selection. I can imagine form-elements like a select-dropdown-box, radio-buttons or checkboxes. All these elements have this kind of code-structure as definition.

So what I did do to remove the error-message is to just define a 'type' for the field:

```
$tmp_ttnews_vp_columns['uid_local:type']['config']['type'] = 'select';
```

On the other hand, the field won't be shown usually, as the table `sys_file_reference` never follows the extbase-logic and is working different.
So it's quite easy and useful to remove some code in the file
`your_extension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_file_reference.php`
There is a block with definitions for new or changed fields in that table and most code above or below that list can be removed.

This is above the column-definitions and can be deleted:
[image]

And a block like this below the desired code can be deleted too:
[image]

The documentation about the `type` field can be found [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/Ctrl/Index.html#type), in the chapter in the bottom is also about the combined notation explained, just not with uid_local but with file: `file:type`.

There are many situations respectively details why it couldn't work, here the known cases, I can extend the list based on comments later:

- The default mapping created by extension-builder looks somehow like this:

```
config.tx_extbase {
persistence {
 classes {

   WDB\TtnewsVp\Domain\Model\FileReference {
     mapping {
       tableName = sys_file_reference
       recordType = Tx_TtnewsVp_FileReference
     }
   }

 }
}
}
```

here the line `recordType = Tx_TtnewsVp_FileReference` is disturbing and provoking the error-message like described in the question.
   This kind of TypoScript is usually in the file `ext_typoscript_setup.typoscript` in the root of the extension-folder, so it's always loaded, even if the static template is not included.

- Annotations in classes might be wrong, including simple faults like typos.
  Annotations and type-hinting have to be correct (perhaps a missing one is better than a wrong one, but I never tried with missing annotations or type-hints).

Comment: Thanks @David for your solution. In my case, the problem occured due to the recordType like u stated. Removing that fixed the problem for me.